# Elasticsearch, Can cluster perform worse than single host server?

Tags: elasticsearch

Based on the past data, I think elasticsearch is not keeping up the requests (to index documents).
And I think it started happening after I made my single host server to multi host cluster.

1. Is it possible to see performance degrade after you add more nodes (Now I have 3 nodes, newly added two machines are not as powerful as the first one)?
2. How can I check if ES is dropping the requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do you have replicas enabled? [By default, Elastic ack´s the index request after all replica shards have been written.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-replication.html) A replica has to be located on a different machine than the primary shard. This can slow down the indexing speed, especially if the replicas are located on slower machines. You can disable this, buying the risk of data loss in node failure scenarios.
2. Check if there are index requests answered with [429 Http Status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) which indicates an overloaded cluster.

**In general: Please have a brief look on this ["How To: Tune for indexing speed"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html)**